# individually process control java or linux script

Tags: java, linux, bash, ubuntu, process

this script will read a text file that we have already filled in as process-list and check if the process names in it are working individually. How can I write Java code or do it with linux script?

Comment: You can use either a IDE or notepad or anything to type it in, really.

Comment: That is typically a scripting scenario you will be faster writing some python or bash script.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line;
do
check = `ps -ef|grep -i $line|grep -v grep |wc -l`
if [ $check -eq 0 ]
then
$line is not running
fi
done<yourTextFile
```

Does this answer your query.?